# iPhone - Download file from the internet and save to documents direcory

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to download files using NSUrlConnection, save the file to the documents directory, and then open it in a webview.

I am using the code:

```
- (IBAction)down:(id)sender {
// create the request
url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlbox.text];
NSLog(@"%@",url);

NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLConnection *theConnection;
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {

    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    receivedData=[NSMutableData data];

}
```

to download files. If someone could give me some code to save the file and open it in a webview, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you have any problems? This isn't a code-on-demand service.

Comment: I have heard this "google" site has a great repository of code

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MGPRemoteAssetController](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MGPRemoteAssetController) which is a plugin I used based on `NSURLConnection`.

More importantly, you can track how MGPRemoteAssetDownloader works. It is a great sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Get the book, "iOS Programming Cookbook" by Vandad Nahavandipoor (O'Reilly) for examples and code to do exactly what you are wanting.  "Programming iOS 5" by Matt Neuburg (also O'Reilly) is helpful too.